# How do you append to a div name that is being dynamically created in a for loop with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, append

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
        var size = skillsArray.length;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            var divString = "'#Skill" + i +"'";
            $(divString).append(skillsArray[i]);
        }
```

To start out my prototype, skillsArray had 5 values.  So my javascript was this:

```
        $('#Skill0').append(skillsArray[0]);
        $('#Skill1').append(skillsArray[1]);
        $('#Skill2').append(skillsArray[2]);
        $('#Skill3').append(skillsArray[3]);
        $('#Skill4').append(skillsArray[4]);
```

My html was this:

```
        <div id='Skill0'></div>
        <div id='Skill1'></div>
        <div id='Skill2'></div>
        <div id='Skill3'></div>
        <div id='Skill4'></div>
```

And everything worked fine.

Now that I want to work with larger dynamically sized arrays, I want to use loops.

So my first step was to write the html div tags out in a javascript loop, which worked:

```
 for (i=0; i<size; i++)
 {
   html += "<div id='Skill" + i + "'></div>";
 }
```

Before I tried step 2 which is what my question is about, it did show the first 5 skills just fine, and every skill after was just blank.   (To be expected since I hadn't updated my javascript yet to do the append to each div, it still only did the first 5.)

So, I was ready to try step 2 and use a for loop for the appends.  How can I do this?  The code I pasted in at the very top did not fill each div with anything at all.

Thanks in advance for the help!
-Holly

Comment: What's inside `skillsArray`?

Comment: here you are creating a `html` variable where is it added to the dom

Comment: is there a container element which holds `<div id='Skill0'></div>` and the likes

Comment: Why the extra quotes... var divString = "#Skill" + i

Comment: It is just strings, and yes I add the html var to the DOM, but since that part was never broken I didn't continue with that snippet.  Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the single quotes in this line : `var divString = "'#Skill" + i +"'";` like this:

```
var divString = "#Skill" + i;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Nikko.  I thought I had tried that, but I must not have.  The things I get stuck on the longest end up being the tiniest errors! :)

Comment: No prob.. I had those kinds of mistakes too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the single quotes in your selector string:

```
var divString = "#Skill" + i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
$("div[id^='Skill']").each(function(i) {
    $(this).append(skillsArray[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in the same loop:

```
var size = skillsArray.length;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // create a div
    var $elem = $("<div id='Skill" + i + "'></div>");

    // append the skills to div
    $elem.append(skillsArray[i]);

    // append the div to body (or wherever)
    $('body').append($elem);
}
```